# Kindle: Change screen boundaries/resolution

Tags: resolution, kindle

Is there any way to change the resolution or set different boundaries for the screen on Amazon Kindle Keyboard? My screen has a crack in a portion of the screen, and I would like to work around it.

I've tried messing around in the filesystem (connected over WiFi), but none of my property changes have had any effect. I assume it would be possible, as it is a Linux OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you can't change ther resoluiton, but for the margins:

> For simple adjustment of the left and right margins to one of the
> three preset values, use the "Words per Line" option on the font size
> page (press Aa key to the right of the spacebar on the keyboard). The
> option may be named "Words per Line" but what it really does is to
> alter the left and right margins.
>
> For finer control of the margins,
> the following steps require the user to access the the Amazon Kindle's
> internal storage memory through a USB cable attached to a computer.
>
> 1. On
>    your Kindle, go to the home page. NOTE: if the next steps are
>    completed while an ebook is open, the change will not take effect.
> 2. Connect your Kindle to your computer with a USB cable.
> 3. Open the folder
>    "system" in the root of the Kindle's internal storage memory. If
>    you're on a Windows machine, this might be hidden from you. Be sure to
>    set Folder Options to ‘Show hidden files, folders, and drives’ and
>    uncheck the ‘Hide unprotected system files’ option. Alternatively, try
>    typing in the system folder's address explicity, e.g. if the Kindle's
>    drive letter is H, the address would be H:\system\ Open the
>    "com.amazon.ebook.booklet.reader" folder.
> 4. Open the "reader.pref" file
>    in a text editor. This is a plain text file with Unix line endings.
> 5. There is a line in reader.pref that starts "HORIZONTAL_MARGIN=".
>    Change the number (Default=40) that follows to the desired number.
>    Margin-widths of 20, 15, and 10 are good starting points for
>    determining what you're most comfortable with. I find that 0 (zero)
>    puts the text too close to the bezel surrounding the display
>    (particularly difficult on the eyes with graphite colored bezel).
> 6. Save
>    and close the file.
> 7. Eject and disconnect the Kindle.
> 8. Restart your
>    Kindle (Menu/Settings/Menu/Restart)
>
> Your default margins when reading
> books have now been changed. If you change the 'Words per Line'
> preference in the Font Size dialog, you will undo the change to the
> margins that you have just made.

Source: http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_HowTo:_Change_Margin